# Able to write the data successfully but not able to read the data from the server

Tags: java, json, sockets

I have two classes server and client. I am running both the server and the client on the intelliji. I am able to write the data to the Json file on the server but when it comes to reading the data, I am not able to read it. My application is not responding when I am trying to read the data. I am new to Socket Programming please help me.

Here is the code on the client side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public String readDataFromServer(Socket socket) throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new 
        InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        return bufferedReader.readLine();
    }

    public  void writeDataToServer(String obj) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1299);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        printWriter.write(obj);
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the code on the server side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    static void writeJson (String str) throws IOException {
        FileWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new FileWriter("MYJSON.json", true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        pw.write(str + '\n');
        pw.flush();
        try {

        } catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
        pw.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1299);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new     InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
        writeJson(str);

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("MYJSON.json");
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);

        printWriter.write(buff.readLine());
        printWriter.flush();  
    }
}
```

I have another class called display controller which is calling the method which is calling the method by passing the socket object. Here is the piece of code from this class.

```
Client client = new Client();
button1.setOnAction(e-> {
            try {
                String str;

              while ((str = client.readDataFromServer(socket)) != null) {

                Object obj = null;
                try {
                  obj = jsonParser.parse(str);
```

What I am doing wrong here? How do I fix it? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in your code.

1. The main one is in the main method of the Server class. Your server only accepts one connection. That connection writes and reads the json file and then your main method ends. If your main program ends, then the server is gone. This means that the first client that connects will work and write to the file, but any subsequent connections will not connect because there's no server accepting connections anymore. Typical servers run indefinitely by using a while loop with `true` as the condition.

Example Structure of a server without threads:

```
    public class Server {

      // this class represents an instance of a client connection to this server
      // It's an object that keeps track of the socket created by referencing
      // the connection.
      private class ClientInstanceOnTheServer {

        private Socket connectionToClient;

        public ClientInstanceOnTheServer(Socket connectionToClient) {
          this.connectionToClient = connectionToClient;
        }

        private void logicToServeAClient() {
          // here goes the logic that serves a client
        }

        public void run () {

          try {
            logicToServeAClient();
          } finally {
            try {
              socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {// handle exceptions!}
          }

        }

      }

      public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
          ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1299);
          while (true) { // run indefinitely
             Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept connections from clients
             // keep track of the socket object as it represents a connection to a client
             // the server is responsible for keeping track of its connections to clients
             // Example:
             ClientInstanceOnTheServer client = new ClientInstanceOnTheServer(socket);
             client.run();
          }
        } finally {
          serverSocket.close();
        }
      }
    }
```

Example Structure of a server with Threads:
NOTE: The code below is not to represent a complete solution with threads, but rather an example to explain how a server works.

```
    public class Server {

      // this class represents an instance of a client connection to this server
      // It's an object that keeps track of the socket created by
      // the connection and it runs in a separate thread to not block
      // the main method thread on this server.
      private class ClientInstanceOnTheServer extends Thread {

        private Socket connectionToClient;

        public ClientInstanceOnTheServer(Socket connectionToClient) {
          this.connectionToClient = connectionToClient;
        }

        private void logicToServeAClient() {
          // here goes the logic that serves a client
        }

        public void run () {

          try {
            logicToServeAClient();
          } finally {
            try {
              socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {// handle exceptions!}
          }

        }

      }

      public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
          ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1299);
          while (true) { // run indefinitely
             Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept connections from clients
             // keep track of the socket object as it represents a connection to a client
             // the server is responsible for keeping track of its connections to clients
             // and it should use a separate thread for each client to not block the main method thread.
             // Example:
             ClientInstanceOnTheServer client = new ClientInstanceOnTheServer(socket);
             client.start(); // this will execute the run method in ClientInstanceOnTheServer class.
          }
        } finally {
          serverSocket.close();
        }
      }
    }
```

2. Your server is always doing both, writing and reading the json file, regardless of what the client wants. The server should somehow allow the client to communicate what it wants to do, and then it executes only what the client asked for. If we use the skeleton code above, this logic would go in the method `logicToServeAClient` of the `ClientInstanceOnTheServer` class. The server and client use the `socket` object's input and output streams to communicate with each other. The server and client need to agree beforehand on which commands/operations the client needs and the server is willing to serve. In your case, it would be `READ` and `WRITE`. Then you create a contract (Protocol) between the client and server on how to send these commands to the server and how the server will respond to the client for each command.

Example of a protocol:

```
// client sends READ to server
// client waits for respond from server
// server read json file and send it to the client

// client sends WRITE to server
// server then waits for the client to send the string to write. 
// Once it receives the string, it writes it to the json file.
```

All of this is achievable using the socket's input and output streams

It's important to distinguish the difference between the `Client` and the `ClientInstanceOnTheServer` classes. Client is your `Client` class that connects to the server and `ClientInstanceOnTheServer` holds the connection and also runs the server code that serves the commands requested by the `Client` class. In the protocol above, whenever client is mentioned, is referring to the `Client` class. Whenever the server is mentioned is referring to the `ClientInstanceOnTheServer` class.

You can find more examples on google, like: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/. However, this should set you up on a path to fix your issue.

Cheers

Comment: You almost get a downvote for the very poorly written threading code, but not quite. `extends Thread` is always a bad idea, and even using `Thread` is generally a bad idea - your code is a prime example why; you in no way monitor the result of your requests - you don't check whether the spun up `Thread` completed successfully or not; and that is the reason that `Thread` is a bad idea - it's actually somewhat tricky to do.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I understand the code is incomplete, but that's intentional. Writing a fully fleshed out server code, as you mentioned, it's tricky to do and goes way beyond the scope of the question asked. The code here serves its purpose, I hope. To answer the question. As for the use of `extends Thread`, I could use `implements Runnable` as an alternative, but somehow we need threads to keep the server accepting connections. If my answer was not clear enough, i'm open to suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Abraham Ciokler Thank you so much bro. It was very helpful. I am new to socket programming so I was having problem but your explanation was really clear. It fixed my issue. God bless you

Comment: Don't use threads at all - handle one connection at a time. Threading is an advanced concept that this user is not ready for - and when they get errors they'll come back there, but with your code they won't be able to explain what the error is or even what the problem is. As to your `Runnable` /`Thread` comment, I'm going to assume it's very early where you are and you haven't had your coffee yet.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see your point now, I updated the answer to include a non threaded way. thanks.

Comment: @Ash I added a non threaded example, in the case you are not savvy with threads yet. cheers.

Comment: @AbrahamCiokler Hi abraham,  for the second issue how do I know if the client is looking to read or write the data. is there any inbuilt method in java that can help us to know that. If I can know what the client wants then only I can do the appropriate action on server. Please help.